# Underline Table Header

Tags: html, css

I got the following HTML:
HTML:

```
<div class="header">
<div class="col col1">1st</div>
<div class="col col2">2nd</div>
<div class="col col3">3rd</div>
<div class="col col4">4th</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
 text-decoration: underline;
}
.col {
width:200px;
float:left;
}
```

What I want do achieve is that

> 1st..............................2nd..................3rd...........4th

is completely underlined. (the complete row)

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A9MxY/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this CSS for desire effect.  Check the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/A9MxY/2/)**.

```
.col{display:inline-block; border-bottom:1px dashed #333333;width:100px;}
```

Comment: I see you've modified your question and now want full bottom border not exactly as posted image.

Comment: The OP always stated "is completely underlined. (the complete row)" @kheema Pandey

Answer (score 4):

use CSS border-style `[border-bottom][1]` dashed

`.col` and margin together

```
.col {
    width:200px;
    border-bottom:2px dashed black;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-left:5px;
}
```

## [DEMO full](http://jsfiddle.net/A9MxY/6/embedded/result/) or [DEMO small](http://jsfiddle.net/A9MxY/6/)

[image]
full code

```
.header {
    text-decoration: underline;

}
.col {
    width:200px;
    border-bottom:2px dashed black;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-left:5px;
}
div{
    float:left;  
}
```

alternative

```
.header {
        text-decoration: underline;
        border-bottom:2px dashed black;
    }
```

[image]

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A9MxY/3/embedded/result/)

full code

```
<div class="header">
   <div class="col col1">1st</div>
   <div class="col col2">2nd</div>
   <div class="col col3">3rd</div>
   <div class="col col4">4th</div>
</div>
```

style

```
.header {
    text-decoration: underline;
    border-bottom:2px dashed black;
}
.col {
width:200px;
}
div{
    float:left;  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `border-bottom: solid 1px;` instead of underline.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HXvnh/4/)

Comment: or you can modify solid with e.g dashed or everything else fits you like here: http://jsfiddle.net/HXvnh/3/

Comment: Don't forget that the poster is asking for the headers to sit along side each other

Answer (score 0):

are you want this
    .col { width:200px; 
           display:inline;
          float:left; 
           border-bottom:1px #000 solid
        }

Answer (score 0):

What you have in your example is `text-decoration: underline` on your `div` - this will underline the text content of that `div`. What we need to do is set each `div` to be `inline-block` so they sit next to each other, and add a border to the container.

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/LUfcV/)